# Passing inferred type into std::find_if lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have the following code.  I'm trying to eliminate the need for explicitly passing the `localization_data_t::language_t` type into the lambda argument.

```
auto language_itr = std::find_if(languages.begin(), languages.end(), [&](const localization_data_t::language_t& language)
{
    return language.code == language_code;
});
```

I assume there is a way to do this since the type of the objects to be iterated over can be derived by the compiler via the iterator's underlying type.  However, I have found no such example in my travels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's always `decltype`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `decltype` in C++11:

```
auto result = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const decltype(*v.begin())& t) { /*   */ });
```

in C++1y you can just use `auto`.

```
auto result = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& t) { /*   */ });
```

There's also `std::iterator_traits` but it's more verbose.

Comment: Ah, there's my problem, I'm not using C++14, my compiler is only C++11. :(  Glad to know that it's being supported somewhere though. :)

Comment: @cmbasnett gcc 4.9 will support them and clang 3.4 already does.

Comment: I'm on the Apple LLVM 5.0 compiler.  `auto` is not supported for function arguments apparently. :/